# Like `Switch()`, but switches to the next observable only when it gets its first element

Tags: rx.net

I'm trying to implement an operator, that I would call `Relay(...)` that will behave mostly like `Switch(IObservable<IObservable<TSource>>)`, with the exception that, instead of switching to the next observable as soon as the source emits it, it will only switch, and unsubscribe to the previous observable, as the next observable emits its first value.  If the next observable terminates without emitting any value, then the previous observable would still unsubscribe and we'd wait for the subsequent observable from the source.

I could do this by simple applying `Switch()` to a source `IObservable<IObservable<TSource>>` that would be modified by another operator `DelayTillFirst(...)` that would delay each notification until the first element is guaranteed to be immediately available, using subjects.

This sounds conceptually relatively simple, however I'm not finding it easy to implement concisely using other operators.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could get what you're after by using `a.TakeUntil(b).Merge(b)` assuming `a` is your previous observable and `b` is the observable you want to switch to as soon as it emits.

```cs
    public class RelayTest : ReactiveTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void ShouldSwitchToSecondObservableAfterSecondObservableEmits()
        {
            var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
            var aCold = scheduler.CreateColdObservable(
                OnNext(500, "a"),
                OnNext(510, "a"),
                OnNext(520, "a")
            );
            var a = aCold.Publish().RefCount();
            var bCold = scheduler.CreateColdObservable(
                OnNext(515, "b"),
                OnNext(520, "b"),
                OnNext(530, "b")
            );
            var b = bCold.Publish().RefCount();
            var relay = a.TakeUntil(b).Merge(b);

            var testableObserver = scheduler.Start(() => relay, Created, Subscribed, Disposed);
            testableObserver.Messages.AssertEqual(
                OnNext(Subscribed + 500, "a"),    
                OnNext(Subscribed + 510, "a"),   
                OnNext(Subscribed + 515, "b"),   
                OnNext(Subscribed + 520, "b"),
                OnNext(Subscribed + 530, "b")
            );
            aCold.Subscriptions.AssertEqual(
                Subscribe(Subscribed, Subscribed + 515)    
            );
            bCold.Subscriptions.AssertEqual(
                Subscribe(Subscribed, Disposed)    
            );
        }
    }
```